# How to trigger Ext.History.on('change', ...) when loading page?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, browser-history

So, I have code like this for Ext.js 4.1.0 (sorry that there are no jsfiddle, it just don't want to work there):

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    var update = function () {
        var params = sidebar.getValues();
        // Updating URL
        var oldToken = Ext.History.getToken();
        var newToken = format_hash({
            name: params.name,
        });
        if (newToken !== oldToken) {
            Ext.History.add(newToken);
        };
    };

    Ext.History.init();
    Ext.History.on('change', function(token) {
        var params = parse_hash(token);
        Ext.getCmp('sidebar_name').setValue(params.name);
    });


    var sidebar = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        id: 'panel',
        renderTo: 'maindiv',
        width: 300,
        bodyPadding: 10,
        frame: true,
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            padding: 5,
            align: 'stretch',
        },
        items: [{
            id: 'sidebar_name',
            fieldLabel: 'Name',
            name: 'name'
        }, {
            text: 'Apply',
            name: 'refresh_button',
            xtype: 'button',
            handler: update,
        }],
    });
});
```

I need form values to update when hash changes. And it works, but not when the page loads first time. How to trigger change event after the page load?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found following workaround. I extract handling of this event into function `on_hash_change` and then just

```
Ext.History.on('change', on_hash_change);
on_hash_change(Ext.History.getToken());
```